# Does the Swing event dispatch thread run at higher priority than the main thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

When I create a Java Swing application without specifying any thread priority levels, does the event dispatch thread run at a higher priority than the main thread? I understand that this does not guarantee that the main thread will never interrupt the event dispatch thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you ever want to make this assumption?

The rule of Swing is that all code that updates the GUI should execute on the EDT so that all updates to Swing components are done in order.

The reason for this rule is you can't control when a thread is interrupted, so you don't want another thread to update the same GUI component at the same, which would leave the component in an inconsistent state, which would cause random problems you wouldn't be able to duplicate.

Comment: The reason for this rule is so as to largely avoid having synchronized methods in Swing.

Answer (score 4):

**Maybe.**

In the implementation I tested, the EDT runs at a higher priority than the main thread when running the following MCVE:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class Test {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getPriority());
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getPriority());
        });
    }
}
```

Output:

```
5
6
```

Note that `5 == Thread.NORM_PRIORITY` and `10 == Thread.MAX_PRIORITY`.

Edited in response to @ellen-spertus' comment.

Comment: Thanks, but while you've shown this to be true for one implementation, I can't find anything in the javadoc to guarantee this is true of all implementations.

Comment: @espertus: and you likely won't

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Then I guess the answer is "maybe", not "yes".